# Porting a Qt project, Debug/Release configurations?

Tags: linux, qt, makefile

Porting a Qt 4.6.3 application from Windows to Linux. The standard way to port a project is to export a .pri file, copy it to the Linux box and then run qmake on it - right? I did that, and I got a makefile. The makefile, however, seems to be tuned to do a release build (up to defining a NO_DEBUG macro); what's the standard way to get a debug build on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your qmake project (.pro) file (which includes your .pri file?), add this to your `CONFIG` variable.

`CONFIG += debug`

More information here: http://pepper.troll.no/s60prereleases/doc/qmake-tutorial.html#making-an-application-debuggable